# Android Login Register Mysql

Tags: android, mysql, authentication, registration

i'm tired, and i dont know how to fix my application .. my problem is, everytime i'm register and filling edittext until click button "register" my application forceclose, but data was entry in mysql .. 
this message

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""

and this my code:

```
private static final String REGISTER_REQUEST_URL = "";
private Map<String, String> params;

public RegisterRequest(String name, String username, String password, int age, String city, String email, int no, Response.Listener<String> listener){
    super(Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
    params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("name", name);
    params.put("username", username);
    params.put("password", password);
    params.put("age", age + "");
    params.put("city", city);
    params.put("email", email);
    params.put("no", no + "");
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getParams(){
    return params;
}
```

}

Comment: Convert your age and no in String

Comment: Obviously the excpetion **is not** from this code but there where are you converting String to int. **Please learn some basics about reading stacktrace**

Answer (score 0):

I would say since you do `no + ""` and no is an int it tries to add "" also as an int. Same thing goes for age.

Edit :
Actually I think it would still work so you're probably trying to convert back an empty string into a number, maybe from a request selecting no or age.